# Interpolating three columns

Tags: r

I have a set of data in ranges like:

```
 x|y|z
-4|1|45
-4|2|68
-4|3|96
-2|1|56
-2|2|65
-2|3|89
 0|1|45
 0|2|56
 0|3|75
 2|1|23
 2|2|56
 2|3|75
 4|1|42
 4|2|65
 4|3|78
```

Here I need to interpolate between x and y using the z value.

I tried interpolating separately for x and y using z value by using the below code:

```
interpol<-approx(x,z,method="linear")
interpol_1<-approx(y,z,method="linear")
```

Now I'm trying to use all the three columns but values are coming wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I need to interpolate x,y and z. say there is a missing value for x,y,z for 1st and 2nd row. We need to find this intermediate missing value for x,y,z column.

Answer (score 1):

In your script you forgot to direct to your `data.frame`. Note the use of `$` in the `approx` function.

```
interpol <- approx(df$x,df$z,method="linear")
interpol_1 <- approx(df$y,df$z,method="linear")
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
           x = c(-4, -4, -4, -2, -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4),
           y = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
           z = c(45, 68, 96, 56, 65, 89, 45, 56, 75, 23, 56, 75, 42, 65, 78)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I tried using dataframe. I looking for code like:    
   interpol <- approx(df$x,df$y,df$z,method="linear") Is there any possiblity to include three columns?

Comment: Are you looking to interpolate from 3 columns? I don't think `approx` supports that.

Comment: yes exactly... then can u suggest me which function supports to interpolate three columns?? @DJV

Comment: yes exactly.. can u please suggest me which function works out to interpolate three columns in R?